# C++ how to use file_mapping, for boost?

Tags: c++, boost

The following codes maps a file into memory and reads the data to the array s. If i try to run this, i get not expected results; it outs memory address of some kind instead of numbers.

```
using namespace boost::interprocess;

// Create the file mapping
file_mapping fm(path.c_str(), read_only);
// Map the file in memory
mapped_region region(fm, read_only);
// Get the address where the file has been mapped
//float * addr = (float *)region.get_address();
std::size_t elements = region.get_size() / sizeof(int);

int *s = (int *)region.get_address();

for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(s)/sizeof(int); i++)
    cout << s[i] << endl;
```

In what format the file must be, and how to make it read ints in the format

`13 45 76 87 45 66756 8765 456`

Comment: Where are you writing the contents to the memory mapped file ?

Comment: `mapped_region region(fm, read_only);` here

Comment: with that you're creating a mapped region, but you need to write on to it first See the example [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0b1/doc/html/interprocess/sharedmemorybetweenprocesses.html#interprocess.sharedmemorybetweenprocesses.mapped_file)

Comment: oh, thanks a lot! Btw, I also like Death Note :D